# Regex for GPA in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl and the world of Regexes, and I'm trying to write a regex that matches a GPA between 0.0 and 4.0. All of the matching values can only be 2 digits separated by a period (`1.2`, `3.4`, `0.2`, etc.).

```
^[0]|[0-3]\.(\d?\d?)|[4].[0]$
```

This is what I have but it's incorrect as it matches  "1.22", "4a0", "14.0", and "2.".  If anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several of the answers here seems unnecessarily complex. Instead, this simple regular expression should do it: `[0-3]\.\d|4\.0`, assuming the single-digit form (e.g. '1') is not valid input. (We don't use GPA where I'm from so I don't know if that is a safe assumption.)

With anchors front and back, as I see others here use:

```
^([0-3]\.\d|4\.0)$
```

Or if you don't need a capturing group:

```
^(?:[0-3]\.\d|4\.0)$
```

A full explanation: the regex matches *either* a 0, 1, 2, or 3 followed by a period and any single digit, OR the literal string 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<!\d)([0-3](\.\d?)|4(\.0)?)(?!\d)
```

It uses `(?<! )` and `(?! )` which is called negative look behind and negative look ahead. This makes sure that `\d` is not present before or after the regex. It is not matched in the regex, just checking it is not after it.
Also, with this regex, you are not limited to values being separated by lines.

*(Modified according to caimarvo suggestion)*

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-3]{1}(\.\d{1}?)(?!\d)|(?<!.)4\.0?(?!.)$
```

This works, same idea looks ahead and behind for extra characters.

Comment: Using `{1}` is pointless; just omit it. Even so, this seems unnecessarily complicated.